# Make ASP.NET site compatible for Blackberry

Tags: css, blackberry

I have a small website in C# / ASP.NET with a couple of forms which looks up data. I need to make this compatible with Blackberry so that users out on site can have the data in hand. I am not looking to make a proper dedicated Blackberry app as such, but to make the current site Blackberry friendly.
Any tips or links would be much appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# and .NET. Please re-tag it appropriately (HTML/CSS/etc).

Comment: please take a look here: http://goo.gl/3fjmz

Comment: thanks, some decent stuff on msdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a look at [these blackberry docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_CSS_512751_11.jsp), this page lists CSS support for blackberry devices, as well as [this page](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=8563&objAction=browse&sort=name).

You will want to look up Responsive Design as a term on google for ways to make your site responsive to different browsers/operating system. Frameworks like Bootstrap & Foundation do a lot of the heavy lifting css/js/html wise for building responsive sites.